# HTML: multiple files in src of script tag

Tags: javascript, html, tags

Today I found HTML tag SCRIPT with two files in src seperated by pipe char.

What does it mean? Never before have I seen it.

It loads both files? Or only `a.js`, if a.js not exist then load `b.js`?

```
<script src="a.js|b.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Where did you see that?

Comment: First code example (beginning with`<!DOCTYPE html>`) at page http://www.abclinuxu.cz/blog/mirecove_dristy/2015/9/reactor.js-moja-odpoved-na-reactjs

Comment: They are comparing two libraries if google translate correctly translated the page. They did not mean to say you should include the libraries like that, but rather it's a means to tell the user to use on of the libraries. So either `<Script  src = "react.js"  type = "text / javascript"  charset = "utf-8"> </ script>` or `<Script  src = "reactor.js"  type = "text / javascript"  charset = "utf-8"> </ script>`

Answer (score 1):

The [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-src-SCRIPT) does not mention such `|` special character, it says that

> this attribute specifies the location of an external script.

As a consequence the content of this attribute should be interpreted by any browser as the URI of a single external script to be loaded.

In your example `a.js|b.js` will be interpreted as a single filename, and not two separate scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It means nothing special as far as the client is concerned. The URL is `a.js|b.js` and that is what the browser asks the server for.

It is possible that the particular server that is hosting that HTML document has a server side program which will interpret that URL to mean "Concatenate the contents of the files `a.js` and `b.js` and send the result back as the HTTP resource", but that's completely transparent to the client.